# printing all the “maps” related to the content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

my content type, plan to have one or more 'maps'.

With the following php code, I can take all their link:

```
 <?php  print render($content['field_mappe_di_riferimento']); ?>
```

and I get the following result:

[image]

I would like to put before the link the image that is within the content type "Mappa", entered in the field "field_immagine_min."

this is the structure of my content type:

[image]

this is the content type "Mappa":

[image]

with: "print_r($field_mappe_di_riferimento);" I get it:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [nid] => 30 [access] => 1 [node] => stdClass Object ( [vid] => 30 [uid] => 1 [title] => Carta di Marignano, primo giorno, 13 Settembre 1515 [log] => [status] => 1 [comment] => 1 [promote] => 1 [sticky] => 0 [nid] => 30 [type] => mappa [language] => en [created] => 1352066743 [changed] => 1352127342 [tnid] => 0 [translate] => 0 [revision_timestamp] => 1352127342 [revision_uid] => 1 [field_battaglia_di_riferimento] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [nid] => 2 ) ) ) [field_immagine_std] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 23 [alt] => [title] => [width] => 672 [height] => 554 [uid] => 1 [filename] => polesella.jpg [uri] => public://polesella_0.jpg [filemime] => image/jpeg [filesize] => 337755 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1352066743 [rdf_mapping] => Array ( ) ) ) ) [field_immagine_min] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [fid] => 24 [alt] => [title] => [width] => 150 [height] => 110 [uid] => 1 [filename] => polesella_small.jpg [uri] => public://polesella_small.jpg [filemime] => image/jpeg [filesize] => 10672 [status] => 1 [timestamp] => 1352066743 [rdf_mapping] => Array ( ) ) ) ) [field_testo_opzionale] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => pisello [format] => [safe_value] => pisello ) ) ) [rdf_mapping] => Array ( [rdftype] => Array ( [0] => sioc:Item [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9c8Y.png) => foaf:Document ) [title] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => dc:title ) ) [created] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => dc:date [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9c8Y.png) => dc:created ) [datatype] => xsd:dateTime [callback] => date_iso8601 ) [changed] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => dc:modified ) [datatype] => xsd:dateTime [callback] => date_iso8601 ) [body] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => content:encoded ) ) [uid] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => sioc:has_creator ) [type] => rel ) [name] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => foaf:name ) ) [comment_count] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => sioc:num_replies ) [datatype] => xsd:integer ) [last_activity] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => sioc:last_activity_date ) [datatype] => xsd:dateTime [callback] => date_iso8601 ) ) [cid] => 0 [last_comment_timestamp] => 1352066743 [last_comment_name] => [last_comment_uid] => 1 [comment_count] => 0 [name] => ant [picture] => 0 [data] => b:0; ) ) )

so I tried to take the nid of the node that I want to take the picture, with success:

```
  print ($content['field_mappe_di_riferimento']['#items'][0][nid]);
```

I get 30...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
$array = $content['field_mappe_di_riferimento']['#items'];

$k = 0;


foreach($array as $k => $v){

  print($k);

  //carico il nodo
  $node = node_view(node_load($content['field_mappe_di_riferimento']['#items'][$k]['nid']));

   //stampa l'img del nodo
   print render($node['field_immagine_min']);

  }
```